# Optimizing database queries

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

My question is when should we worry about how much data do we ask for a given task from sql database?

Lets say I have PostgreSql database. I have a product table and product has 20 fields.

In a the system some places actually only need product id, name and price. Some people argue, that I should only ask those 3 fields from the database to be efficient. But I feel It's much easier for developers to always do `productService.getProduct(id)` and then pick the fields they need, than to make a separate class or query for those specific fields.

Does it really matter - for speed of the query - if I ask 3 or 20 fields? How much load could it increase?

(I'm java developer with the mindset of "Early optimization is the root of all evil".)

Comment: If you only ask for 3 fields, you only get 3 fields instead if N, therefore less data has to be transfered from database server to connected app. Its simple

Comment: the main difference will be in transport between your client and your db + serialization/deserialization

Comment: I'm afraid it is too broad/primarily opinion-based

Comment: Making a separate query for every possible combination of fields that could be desired is most likely premature optimization; however, pulling data for fields that are rarely used is not a "better" option either. The best solution as is often the case is situationally dependent; but a simple starting point could be a two method solution such as a  `getProductInfo()` and `getFullProductInfo()` methods. As far as, _"Does it really matter...?"_ goes; it does if your products can contain blob(s) for images or long text descriptions that are only actually needed in a relatively few places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all optimization, when it matters. The profiler and other tools (for example postgres' [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html)) will let you know.

The actual mechanisms depend on lots of things; the database being used, table/schema, tablespace settings etc. etc. so it's impossible to give any definite answer, but since the amount of data being moved is different, it will naturally make a difference whether you're moving 100,000 rows of 10 columns or 100,000 rows of 3 columns.

The actual query may not see a significant difference if the same amount of pages is being read from disk, but the memory and network use will naturally differ.

Thankfully you can refactor code and queries to select less data if the original query becomes a bottleneck.